# How to calculate time difference between two dates in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which is having multiple rows with column date. date column is having date and time. not each row has incremental time so I want to calculate after each row how much was the time difference between current and previous date in seconds.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods = 10, freq ='H')
```

In the above snippet time difference after each step is 1hr which means 3600 seconds so I want a list of tuple having `[(<prev date time>, <current_datetime>, <time_difference>),.....]`.

Answer (score 1):

> **I want a list of tuple** having [(prev date time, current_datetime,
> time_difference),.....]

In this case, use [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and compute the time difference with [`tolal_seconds`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) :

```
data = pd.date_range("1/1/2011", periods = 10, freq ="H")
​
L = list(zip(data.shift(), # <- previous time
             data,         # <- current time
            (data.shift() - data).total_seconds())) # <- time diff
```

NB : If you manipulate a *dataframe*, you need to replace `data` by `df["date_column"]`.

​
Output :

```
print(L)

[(Timestamp('2011-01-01 01:00:00', freq='H'),
  Timestamp('2011-01-01 00:00:00', freq='H'),
  3600.0),
 (Timestamp('2011-01-01 02:00:00', freq='H'),
  Timestamp('2011-01-01 01:00:00', freq='H'),
  3600.0),
 (Timestamp('2011-01-01 03:00:00', freq='H'),
  Timestamp('2011-01-01 02:00:00', freq='H'),
  3600.0),
 (Timestamp('2011-01-01 04:00:00', freq='H'),
  Timestamp('2011-01-01 03:00:00', freq='H'),
  3600.0),
 (Timestamp('2011-01-01 05:00:00', freq='H'),
  Timestamp('2011-01-01 04:00:00', freq='H'),
  3600.0),
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `diff` function in Pandas to calculate the time difference between consecutive rows in the data column. Here's an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": pd.date_range("1/1/2011", periods=10, freq="H")})

# Calculate the time difference between consecutive rows in seconds
df["time_diff"] = df["date"].diff().dt.total_seconds()

# Create a list of tuples
result = [(df.iloc[i-1]["date"], row["date"], row["time_diff"]) for i, row in df[1:].iterrows()]
```

`df`:

```
    date                time_diff
0   2011-01-01 00:00:00       NaN
1   2011-01-01 01:00:00    3600.0
2   2011-01-01 02:00:00    3600.0
3   2011-01-01 03:00:00    3600.0
4   2011-01-01 04:00:00    3600.0
5   2011-01-01 05:00:00    3600.0
6   2011-01-01 06:00:00    3600.0
7   2011-01-01 07:00:00    3600.0
8   2011-01-01 08:00:00    3600.0
9   2011-01-01 09:00:00    3600.0
```

`result`:

```
[(Timestamp('2011-01-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2011-01-01 01:00:00'), 3600.0),
 (Timestamp('2011-01-01 01:00:00'), Timestamp('2011-01-01 02:00:00'), 3600.0),
 (Timestamp('2011-01-01 02:00:00'), Timestamp('2011-01-01 03:00:00'), 3600.0),
 (Timestamp('2011-01-01 03:00:00'), Timestamp('2011-01-01 04:00:00'), 3600.0),
 (Timestamp('2011-01-01 04:00:00'), Timestamp('2011-01-01 05:00:00'), 3600.0),
 (Timestamp('2011-01-01 05:00:00'), Timestamp('2011-01-01 06:00:00'), 3600.0),
 (Timestamp('2011-01-01 06:00:00'), Timestamp('2011-01-01 07:00:00'), 3600.0),
 (Timestamp('2011-01-01 07:00:00'), Timestamp('2011-01-01 08:00:00'), 3600.0),
 (Timestamp('2011-01-01 08:00:00'), Timestamp('2011-01-01 09:00:00'), 3600.0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this with [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). `[:-1]` is required because we get a list of 10 intervals just using shift, but there are N-1 intervals between N points.

```py
result = [(i[0],
           i[1],
           (i[1] - i[0]).total_seconds())
          for i in list(zip(data, data.shift(1)))[:-1]]

print(result)
[(Timestamp('2011-01-01 00:00:00', freq='H'),
  Timestamp('2011-01-01 01:00:00', freq='H'),
  3600.0),
 (Timestamp('2011-01-01 01:00:00', freq='H'),
  Timestamp('2011-01-01 02:00:00', freq='H'),
  3600.0),
 (Timestamp('2011-01-01 02:00:00', freq='H'),
  Timestamp('2011-01-01 03:00:00', freq='H'),
  3600.0),
 (Timestamp('2011-01-01 03:00:00', freq='H'),
  Timestamp('2011-01-01 04:00:00', freq='H'),
  3600.0),
 (Timestamp('2011-01-01 04:00:00', freq='H'),
  Timestamp('2011-01-01 05:00:00', freq='H'),
  3600.0),
 (Timestamp('2011-01-01 05:00:00', freq='H'),
  Timestamp('2011-01-01 06:00:00', freq='H'),
  3600.0),
 (Timestamp('2011-01-01 06:00:00', freq='H'),
  Timestamp('2011-01-01 07:00:00', freq='H'),
  3600.0),
 (Timestamp('2011-01-01 07:00:00', freq='H'),
  Timestamp('2011-01-01 08:00:00', freq='H'),
  3600.0),
 (Timestamp('2011-01-01 08:00:00', freq='H'),
  Timestamp('2011-01-01 09:00:00', freq='H'),
  3600.0)]
```